# What makes the blockchain immutable in Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper, proof-of-work

In Proof-of-Work, it's difficult to edit/delete data on the blockchain because of the millions of hashes performed before generating a block. It would be impossible for a single attacker to have 51% of the computational capacity of the whole network which makes it difficult for him/her to tamper with the data. How is immutability achieved in Proof-of-Stake?